# How to add hover effect to button using Revolution slider in word press

Tags: wordpress

Am using Revolution slider in wordpress how to give hover effect to button please any one help me.
 Am created class for that am written css but its not taking.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your code and explain what is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually quite easy.

Once you add a button layer, you can choose an idle and hover state color. If you have already added a button layer you can right-click on the button itself, choose "Style" > "Advanced Layer CSS" and you will have two tabs - one is for idle and one for hover.

In both tabs you can enter background-color and choose what color should be displayed for idle button and hovered button.

Answer (score 0):

In Slider Revolution 6, it is in "Layer options -> Hover"
There you can set it all for hover state